# What are the ways to mark a bean (Prototype) in Spring for deletion?

Tags: spring, prototype

When we specify a bean with a - prototype scope, Spring does not monitor the lifecycle of such a component.

However, I cannot use scope Request or Session.

How can we tell Spring that such a component needs to be marked for deletion?
If I missed something and there is a misunderstanding of how it works correctly,
Please tell me.

What ideas does anyone have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681027/do-spring-prototype-beans-need-to-be-destroyed-manually